# Is it possible to set a different behavior for "back" and "Forward" buttons of the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have only one HTML page, but I simulate the pages with javascript hiding the content:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function show(page_name) {
        var pages = document.getElementsByClassName("pages");
        for (var i=0; i<pages.length; i++) {
          pages.item(i).style.display='none';
        }
        document.getElementById(page_name).style.display='block';
        return false;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page1" class="pages" style="display:block">
      <h2>Page1</h2>
      <p><a href="#" onclick="return show('page2')">page2</a></p>
      <p><a href="#" onclick="return show('page3')">page3</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="pages" style="display:none">
      <h2>Page2</h2>
      <p><a href="#" onclick="return show('page1')">page1</a></p>
      <p><a href="#" onclick="return show('page3')">page3</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="page3" class="pages" style="display:none">
      <h2>Page3</h2>
      <p><a href="#" onclick="return show('page2')">page1</a></p>
      <p><a href="#" onclick="return show('page2')">page2</a></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to make the browser capable of back and forward through my "virtual" pages?

Comment: This is done not so much by overriding the back- and forward button **click** behaviour per se, but by using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and responding to forwards and backwards events (emitted by the user pressing forward or backward button, or by your code).

Comment: `history.pushState` is what you need to look into. it would let you remove that nasty js code from your html links too, which makes you look stronger and take advantage of bookmarking dynamic "pages".